# Using Windows Credentials to do Basic Auth in Python

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, basic-authentication, ntlm

I am writing a Python application to download csv files through an API on an internal server, by sending GET requests. When testing the requests through Postman, I was able to use Basic Auth along with my Windows credentials to generate a token and authenticate on the server.

Now when it comes to the Python application, I obviously don't want to hard-code my Windows credentials into the app, nor do I want to use the Basic Auth token that was generated (maybe I'm wrong, but this still seems like it would not be a very secure thing to do as I believe the token is a direct hash of my credentials, not to mention when I change my credentials I would have to go and update the token as well).

What I want to know is if it is possible to automatically use the windows credentials from wherever the program is run, in order to authenticate against the server. I tried using NTLM, but unless I am misunderstanding this would still require my credentials to be coded into the app, and from my testing it looks like the server only supports basic auth and not NTLM directly.

I am very new to authentication in Python (and in general), any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you intend to use some continuous integration tool like `TeamCity` you'll be able to create environmental variables with hidden values and use them in your `Python` code as `os.environ['your_var']`. This should allow to avoid sensitive data leakage

Comment: This is really just a one-off application that's going to run nightly and pull daily csv data files. A CI tool seems like overkill for such a need. I'm sure my use case isn't that uncommon...is the standard procedure really just to generate a token and put that in the code? Or possibly to create a service account and use those credentials, rather than my personal Windows ones?